# systemctl show does not show several properties

Tags: linux, systemd, systemctl

I am working with `systemctl` to get value of the **EnvironmentFile** property from *ssh.service* unit file using the command `systemctl show ssh.service -p EnvironmentFile` but it returns empty result.

The unit file itself contains this property. For example my unit file looks like this (`cat /lib/systemd/system/ssh.service`):

```
[Unit]
Description=OpenBSD Secure Shell server
After=network.target auditd.service
ConditionPathExists=!/etc/ssh/sshd_not_to_be_run

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/ssh
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $SSHD_OPTS
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure
RestartPreventExitStatus=255
Type=notify

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=sshd.service
```

Moreover if I do `systemctl show ssh.service | grep EnvironmentFile` I get:

```
EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/ssh (ignore_errors=yes)
```

Almost all other properties work as expected, for example `systemctl show ssh.service -p After` returns extended dependencies:

```
After=network.target auditd.service systemd-journald.socket basic.target sysinit.target system.slice
```

The same problem with the property **ConditionPathExists**, but in this case even grep doesn't show this property (`systemctl show ssh.service | grep ConditionPathExists` prints nothing).

Why does this happen? And how to get **EnvironmentFile** property from a unit file without using `grep`?

Answer (score 1):

I've reproduced the issue with the missing `EnvironmentFile` in systemd 229 and cross referenced the documentation for `systemctl` as well as the `NEWS` file from the latest release of `systemd` to see if there are mentions of this behavior being changed. There is not.

This appears to be a bug in `systemd`. The documentation for `systemctl` implies this will work, when reviewing the documentation for `show` and `--property`. As you noted, the property is definitely there if you grep for it.

I encourage you to search through the [existing open issues for systemd](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/) to see if there's an already an open issue for this. If not, open a new Issue report.

If the behavior is working as intended, then the `man systemctl` docs should be updated to clarify that.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by [Mark Stosberg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43283164/5648958) I tried to search for open issue related to this problem and I've found [one](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/5137) which describes wrong autocompletion behavior regarding to Environment* properties.

Using **busctl** I've found out that the actual property name is **EnvironmentFiles** (`busctl introspect org.freedesktop.systemd1 /org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/ssh_2eservice | grep EnvironmentFile`):

```
.EnvironmentFiles                   property  a(sb)          1 "/etc/default/ssh" true                const
```

So if you need to get this property from **systemctl** you have to execute `systemctl show -p EnvironmentFiles ssh.service` (output below):

```
EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/ssh (ignore_errors=yes)
```